# how to htaccess redirect *.html/ to *.html

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone help me add the right line to htaccess that will redirect URLs that end with .html/

to

.html

For example, http://mysite.com/page.html/ should 301 redirect to http://mysite.com/page.html

Comment: And exactly why do you want this?

Comment: Because it creates duplicate content on my site. Both addresses show the same content and I'd like to have a single canonical version.

Comment: @nightcracker it's because of SEO "shmeo" stuff i think.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want a single canonical version, why not [say so](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in your document?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page.html" />
```

If you do however feel the need to do redirects, then you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*\.html)/$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Yes, but it won't redirect the users. I'd like them to only be able to view the page through a single URL

Comment: @RoyPeleg it will tell search engines how to index your pages properly, and people couldn't care less about whether or not your urls end with a trailing slash

Comment: Yea, I know what the tag does, however this isn't what I've asked for. I'd them to access the page through a single URL.

Answer (score 0):

So how about this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*\.html)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This does redirect users with a 301.

Comment: I need a one-line solution, got 1,000s of pages, I won't create one line for each of them.